# LG G6 - "Charging blocked, moisture detected", would rooting help?

Tags: charging, lg, lg-g6

When I charge my LG G6, I randomly get the error message "Charging Blocked - Moisture Detected".

I sent it back to LG, but they said I was no longer covered by warranty because the SIM card tray is broken. They said it will cost me $100+ to fix the software, which makes me think that I can fix this by changing the software on the phone.

Would rooting my phone solve this software specific issue?

Comment: Have you submerged your phone in the water?

Comment: Your warranty should cover the damage SIM card tray.. I believe that this can't be fixed with a simple software modifications because the device is probably identifying a short circuit that is most likely caused by moisture shorting out the chip board... Maybe try drying your device for a few days and try again.

Comment: @LloydDominic I did not.

Comment: @Zillinium Apparently the warranty does not cover physical damage such as a broken sim card tray. I've had my device in dry conditions for weeks at a time but I still get this message occasionally.

Comment: I did not submerge my phone but it started appearing couple of days back and only goes away after all the charge has drained and I have let it for at least few hours. Any resolutions?

Comment: The only resolution I have is to use a wireless charger instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your charging port. There might be water there.

Comment: No there is no water or dirt there. I've used paper to clean it, and its been in dry conditions for several days.

Comment: Hmm. Try factory resetting?

Comment: I did a factory reset several times, but I always end up with the same issue.